# iptables - "bad argument DROP" when run inside a FOR loop via ssh command

Tags: ssh, iptables

I am trying to add a list of ip addresses to an iptables chain on a remote server. If I ssh into the server and run the command it works as desired (I manually populate the array once I have ssh'd into the server for testing for this code, otherwise the array is populated on the local server):

```
for IP in ${aryTEST[@]}; do sudo iptables -A test -s $IP -j DROP ; done
```

But when I try run it as an ssh command it fails with the error

> Bad argument `DROP'

The command I run is:

```
 ssh -p <port#> <user>@<host> "for IP in ${aryTEST[@]}; do sudo iptables -A test -s $IP -j DROP ; done"
```

When I try it with single quotes around the command it doesn't return an error and appears to work, but when I check the chain it is empty.

```
ssh -p <port#> <user>@<host> 'for IP in ${aryTEST[@]}; do sudo iptables -A test -s $IP -j DROP ; done'
```

The user has been added to sudoers to be able to run iptables without a password for testing purposes. Currently I am having to loop through the array and run each ip address on a separate ssh connection. Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Thanks @anx, I assume you mean the first $ interpreted via the remote shell is the first code example above and the second $ interpreted locally is in the ssh command? If so that is what I want. The array needs to be interpreted in the local shell as that is where the array is. I did some testing by simply echoing the ${aryTEST[@]} to a file on the remote machine to make sure it works as desired. The first code example above was my testing to add rules via a loop.

Comment: @anx I understand your comment now. when i was testing it i was only \ the array and ignoring $IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Escape the dollar sign (`$`) you wish to preserve using a backslash (`\`).**

If you use

```
 ssh -p <port#> <user>@<host> "for IP in ${aryTEST[@]}; do sudo iptables -A test -s $IP -j DROP ; done"
```

This is what it looks on the remote server (on `<host>`) - the `$IP` parameter is already evaluated (to nothing), hence the `bad argument` compltaint from iptables:

```
for IP in 192.0.2.1 192.0.2.3 192.0.2.7; do sudo iptables -A test -s  -j DROP ; done
```

But what you want it to look like is:

```
for IP in 192.0.2.1 192.0.2.3 192.0.2.7; do sudo iptables -A test -s $IP -j DROP ; done
```

So you need to have the array evaluated on your end, while the other variable is only evaluated on the remote side:

```
ssh -p <port#> <user>@<host> "for IP in ${aryTEST[@]}; do sudo iptables -A test -s \$IP -j DROP ; done"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create an IPSet rule file `testset.ipset` which lists your IP addresses:

```
create testset hash:ip family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
add testset <IP1>
add testset <IP2>
...
```

Then, transfer the file to remote host and run the following:

```
ipset restore -! < testset.ipset

iptables -A test -p tcp -m set --match-set testset src -j DROP
```

This creates the IPSet from your definition, and then adds firewall rule to block packets coming from this set of IP addresses.